# How do I get the top N filter to show the correct values in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to show the top-most delayed airline routes in this dataset. Whenever I leave it unfiltered, I can see the most delayed set that I want to show. However, as soon as I apply a top N filter, it gives me a different list. I'm not sure what's happening here or how to fix it.

Link to workbook https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/shannon.ashberry/viz/FlightDelaysandCancellations_16448265391280/Top10MostDelayedRoutes?publish=yes

I hope the community can help.

Thanks,
Shannon
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcXX.png)
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEw2a.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some of your filters to be applied first, and then compute the top 10 filter upon the results that pass the first filter. To make a filter take effect earlier, you can right click on the field in the filter shelf and add it to the *context* of your viz.

Search for “order of operations” in the tableau help for more info.